# Installing composer in godaddy shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have Laravel 5.1 up and running in my shared hosting in GoDaddy. In the installation I have `composer.json` and `composer.lock` does it means composer is already installed? Also, if I try to get the composer version typing `composer -V` in my ssh, I get `-bash: composer: command not found`. Also, if I do need to install `composer` do I need to install it in the `root` or in `public_html`.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to install composer manually through `DRUSH`, a command-line utility for cPanel: https://www.godaddy.com/help/how-to-install-drush-on-cpanel-shared-hosting-12396

**EDIT: Google is your best friend**

http://endlessgeek.com/2014/03/install-drush-cpanel-shared-hosting/

**UPDATE (broken link): archive.org too**

https://web.archive.org/web/20180623051704/http://endlessgeek.com:80/2014/03/install-drush-cpanel-shared-hosting/

[https://duckduckgo.com/?q=install+composer+through+drush](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=install%20composer%20through%20drush)

[GiorgosK answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/260134) to [Install Drush on shared hosting with SSH access?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/236324)

Comment: This link is broken. can you provide new active link

Answer (score -1):

I followed the link in the previous answer to install Drush then successfully created a new laravel 5.1 project using the command line

Try using:  php composer.phar -v instead of composer -v
You'll need to be in the directory of the composer.phar file to use it

Just set this up on my GoDaddy CPanel Shared hosting

Hope this helps